# RoR: Creating an Object with string primary_key (associated error: Couldn't find Object_Id with ID=0)

Tags: database, string, ruby-on-rails-3, primary-key

I created a model that had a string primary_key.

The Create action in Ruby on Rails gave me the following error:

```
Couldn't find Theme with ID=0
```

My Theme table has no ID column, but a string column called name which is the primary key.

After searching everywhere, I experimented myself with the Create action inside the theme_controller.

It initially was:

```
def create
    @theme = Theme.new(params[:theme])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @theme.save
    ....
```

The :name parameter was being correctly passed, but was not being used, it was being replaced by an ID which my model does not have.

**The solution** was to insert the following line to force RoR to take the name into the object.

```
def create
    @theme = Theme.new(params[:theme])
    @theme.name = params[:theme][:name]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @theme.save
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set the primary key in the model of Theme. Like

```
set_primary_key :name
```

and also disable id's in the migration like

```
create_table :themes, :id => false do |t|
```

Please also see http://roninonrails.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-non-standard-primary-keys-with.html for more information on the same. The approach you have is not required as Theme.new(params[:theme]) is supposed to automatically fill all the attributes in the model if the params[:theme] has the same attributes as that of the model. Not sure why its not working that way.

Comment: Came through this same issue today in another project.
Had used set_primary_key and :id => false.
Result was the same, and solution was the same. I did not test your link since the proposed solution is much more complex.